# ansible shell is not creating nohup.out when nohup is used

Tags: ansible

I wrote a simple task to echo a text and wrapped it around nohup command. usually, when I execute `nohup echo test` nohup.out is created in the same working directory. When I'm doing this from ansible, nohup.out is completely missing

```
- name: nohup
  tags: nohup
  shell: 'nohup echo test'
  args:
    chdir: /tmp
    executable: /bin/bash
  async: 45
  poll: 0
```

What's wrong with above? Why nohup.out is not showing up?

Comment: the nohup.out file will be on the target server, not your local host.

Comment: Yes, I know that. I was checking remote location for that file in both /tmp and $HOME (just in case), but the file is not present.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So according to nohup's documentation

> If standard input is a terminal, redirect it from an unreadable file. 
>   If standard output is a terminal, append output to 'nohup.out' if
>   possible, '$HOME/nohup.out' otherwise.

Ansible seems to not work this way hence no nohup.out file is being created. To workaround this problem I have modified task in following way

```
- name: nohup
  tags: nohup
  shell: 'nohup echo test > nohup.out 2>&1 &'
  args:
    chdir: /tmp
    executable: /bin/bash
  become: yes
  become_user: user
  become_method: su
```

Key part here is `> nohup.out 2>&1 &` within `shell` command. Last three lines regarding `become` technique is not that relevant here.

Finally, **nohup.out** is present where I needed it and contains all data I wanted.